# OverFlowError: math range error javaScript to python

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to build an Action potential simulation (a graph of voltage relative to time, where the voltage values are obtained through numerically solving a couple of differential equiations). I have used the code from an online simulation of this in javaScript and am trying to translate it into python. However, due to the different ways in which python and java handle floats, I get an Overflowerror: math range error. Does anyone know how I can circumvent this in this specific situation? I am posting everything i've written and my error output:

```
    import numpy as np
    import math
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
    import random

    class HH():
        def __init__(self):

            self.dt = 0.025 
            self.Capacitance = 1
            self.GKMax = 36
            self.GNaMax = 120
            self.Gm = 0.3
            self.EK = 12
            self.ENa = 115
            self.VRest = 10.613
            self.V = 0
            self.n = 0.32
            self.m = 0.05
            self.h = 0.60
            self.INa = 0
            self.IK = 0
            self.Im = 0 
            self.Iinj = 0
            self.tStop = 200
            self.tInjStart = 25
            self.tInjStop = 175
            self.IDC = 0
            self.IRand = 35
            self.Itau = 1


        @classmethod
        def alphaN(cls,V):
            if(V == 10):
                return alphaN(V+0.001)
            else:
                a = (10-V)/(100 * (math.exp((10-V)/10) -1))
                print("alphaN: ", a)
                return a 

        @classmethod
        def betaN(cls,V):
            a = 0.125*math.exp(-V/80)
            print("betaN: ", a)
            return a

        @classmethod
        def alphaM(cls, V):
            if (V == 25): 
                return alphaM(V+0.0001)
            else: 
                a =  (25 - V)/10 * (math.exp( (25-V)/10) - 1)
                print("alphaM", a)
                return (a)
        @classmethod
        def betaM(cls, V):
            return 4 * math.exp(-V/18)

        @classmethod
        def alphaH(cls, V):
            return 0.07 * math.exp(-V/20)

        @classmethod
        def betaH(cls, V):
            return 1/(math.exp((30-V/10)+1))


        def iteration(self):

            aN = self.alphaN(self.V)
            bN = self.betaN(self.V)
            aM = self.alphaM(self.V)
            bM = self.betaM(self.V)
            aH = self.alphaH(self.V)
            bH = self.betaH(self.V)
            tauN = 1/(aN + bN)
            print("tauN: ", tauN)
            tauM = 1/(aM + bM)
            print("tauM", tauM)
            tauH = 1/(aH + bH)
            print("tauH: ", tauH)
            nInf = aN * tauN
            print("nInf: ", nInf)
            mInf = aM * tauM
            print("mInf: ", mInf)
            hInf = aH * tauH
            print("hInf: ", hInf)

            self.n += self.dt/ tauN * (nInf - self.n)
            print("n: ", self.n)
            self.m += self.dt/tauM * (mInf - self.m)
            print("m: ", self.m)
            self.h += self.dt/tauH * (hInf - self.h)
            print("h: ", self.h)

            self.IK = self.GKMax * self.n * self.n * self.n * self.n * (self.VRest - self.EK)
            print("IK: ", self.IK)
            self.INa = self.GNaMax * self.m * self.m * self.m * self.h * (self.VRest - self.ENa)
            print("INa: ", self.INa)
            self.Im =  self.Gm * (self.VRest * self.V)
            print("Im: ", self.Im)
            self.V += self.dt/self.Capacitance * (self.INa + self.IK + self.Im + self.Iinj)  
            print("V: ", self.V)
            print("nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn")
            return self.V


    if __name__ == '__main__':

        hodgkinHuxley = HH()

        V_vector = np.zeros(math.floor(hodgkinHuxley.tStop/hodgkinHuxley.dt))   #v_vector
        Iinj_vector = np.zeros(math.floor(hodgkinHuxley.tStop/hodgkinHuxley.dt)) #stim_vector
        n_vector = np.zeros(math.floor(hodgkinHuxley.tStop/hodgkinHuxley.dt))
        m_vector = np.zeros(math.floor(hodgkinHuxley.tStop/hodgkinHuxley.dt))
        h_vector = np.zeros(math.floor(hodgkinHuxley.tStop/hodgkinHuxley.dt))

        plotSampleRate = math.ceil(hodgkinHuxley.tStop/2000/hodgkinHuxley.dt) #t_vector
        print("plotsamplerate: ", plotSampleRate)
        i = 0
        t_vector = []
        for t in range(0, hodgkinHuxley.tStop+1):
            t= t+hodgkinHuxley.dt
            if(math.floor(t)>hodgkinHuxley.tInjStart & math.ceil(t)<hodgkinHuxley.tInjStop):
                rawInj  = hodgkinHuxley.IDC + hodgkinHuxley.IRand * 2 * (random.random()-0.5)
            else:
                rawInj = 0

            hodgkinHuxley.Iinj += hodgkinHuxley.dt/hodgkinHuxley.Itau * (rawInj - hodgkinHuxley.Iinj)  
            hodgkinHuxley.iteration()
            counter = 0 
            if(i == plotSampleRate):
                V_vector[counter] = hodgkinHuxley.V
                Iinj_vector[counter] = hodgkinHuxley.Iinj
                n_vector[counter] = hodgkinHuxley.n
                m_vector[counter] = hodgkinHuxley.m
                h_vector[counter] = hodgkinHuxley.h
                i=0;
                counter+=1
            i+=1
```

Error:

```
    plotsamplerate:  4
    alphaN:  0.05819767068693265
    betaN:  0.125
    alphaM 27.956234901758684
    tauN:  5.458584687514421
    tauM 0.03129279788667988
    tauH:  14.285714285707257
    nInf:  0.3176769140606974
    mInf:  0.8748288084532805
    hInf:  0.9999999999995081
    n:  0.31998936040167786
    m:  0.7089605789167688
    h:  0.6006999999999995
    IK:  -0.5235053389507994
    INa:  -2681.337959108097
    Im:  0.0
    V:  -67.0465366111762
    nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
    alphaN:  0.00034742442109860416
    betaN:  0.2889909708647963
    alphaM 91515.37543280824
    tauN:  3.456160731837547
    tauM 1.0907358211913938e-05
    tauH:  0.5000401950825147
    nInf:  0.0012007546414823879
    mInf:  0.9981909817434281
    hInf:  1.0
    n:  0.31768341581102577
    m:  663.6339264765652
    h:  0.6206633951393696
    IK:  -0.5085774931025618
    INa:  -2272320232559.0464
    Im:  -213.46946791632385
    V:  -56808005886.37157
    nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Huinqk 2.0\Documents\projects\python\tariq_neural networks\plotting function.py", line 131, in <module>
        hodgkinHuxley.iteration()
      File "C:\Users\Huinqk 2.0\Documents\projects\python\tariq_neural networks\plotting function.py", line 71, in iteration
        aN = self.alphaN(self.V)
      File "C:\Users\Huinqk 2.0\Documents\projects\python\tariq_neural networks\plotting function.py", line 38, in alphaN
        a = (10-V)/(100 * (math.exp((10-V)/10) -1))
    OverflowError: math range error
    [Finished in 0.8s]
```

Comment: Forgot to include original source: http://myselph.de/hodgkinHuxley.html

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
This code is not at all minimal, and you haven't specified what you want as a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write an altered version of `math.exp` which will behave more like the javascript function.

```
def safe_exp(n):
    try:
        return math.exp(n)
    except OverflowError:
        return float('inf')
```

Comment: follow up: that did work, however the overflow was due to a different mistake in the code, therefore I didn't really need it.

Answer (score 0):

`OverflowError: math range error` mean that's `math.exp((10-V)/10)` slightly outside of the range of a double, so it causes an overflow...

You may expect that this number is infinite with:

```
try:
    a = (10-V)/(100 * (math.exp((10-V)/10) -1))
except OverflowError:
    a = (10-V)/(float('inf'))
```

Comment: I do underastand that bit, however I am asking what to do in order to solve this, because a = (10-V)/(100 * (math.exp((10-V)/10) -1)) is a constant necessary to derive the value of V. What can I do to get a value of a, that will not mess up my results too mach, is rounding it up an option?